# navigation.goBack wrong behavior - Stack inside a Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I think its a bug, the problem is as fallow:

I have this (stacks navigators inside a tab navigator):

- A tab

  - Aa stack
  - Ab stack

Where:

- Ab stack

  - Aba component
  - Abb component

When I use navigation.goBack() function in Abb component, goBack function send me to Aa stack instead Aba component.

It's a strange behavior cause if I press Android back button sends me to Aba component and that is how navigation.goBack should work I think.

---

**This is my Ab stack**

```
const ComplementFormStack = ({ navigation, route, onSetGoToSyncData }) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="ComplementForms"
      screenOptions={{
        ...stackScreenOptions({
          onPressLeftIcon:
            route?.state?.index > 0 ? navigation.goBack : navigation.openDrawer,
          onPressRightIcon: onSetGoToSyncData,
          index: route?.state?.index
        })
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ComplementForms"
        component={ComplementForms}
        options={{
          title: "Formularios"
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="FilterIndividualTable"
        component={FilterIndividualTable}
        options={{
          title: "Filtros de busqueda"
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**this is my A tab:**

```
const SettingsTab = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="DataRecorded" backBehavior="order">
    <Tab.Screen
      name="DataRecorded"
      component={DataRecordedStack}
      options={{
        title: "Registros"
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="ComplementForms"
      component={ComplementFormsStack}
      options={{
        title: "Formularios"
      }}
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);
```

**this is stackScreenOptions , if you want to know:**

```
const stackScreenOptions = ({
  onPressLeftIcon = () => {},
  onPressRightIcon = () => {},
  index
}) => {
  return {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      height: hp(8.3)
    },
    headerTintColor: Color.primary.dark,
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontSize: hp(2.6),
    },
    headerLeft: () => {
      if (index > 0) {
        return <GoBackBtn onPress={onPressLeftIcon} />;
      }
      return <ButtonDrawer onPress={onPressLeftIcon} />;
    },
    headerRight: () => {
      return <SyncButton onPress={onPressRightIcon} />;
    }
  };
};
```